# Cannot convert JSON into Objects

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

i All,

The Project: A handy utility for tickets at work to help sort and manage my tickets, built on top of our provider's API.

My Background: I'm like 19 hours total into dart and am almost done with my first bootcamp.

The GIST: I have started writing a provider for our helpdesk software's API. I am sending requests to the API successfully but I am utterly clueless on transforming the data into an actual map to generate ticket instances with.

What I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Fetch the data from the API
2. Convert that String into a MAP of json objects that I can iterate
   through
3. Iterate through the JSON objects to create instances of ticket
   objects with
4. build a list of those ticket objects and return it to requestor to
   generate a widget list.

I could swear I've done everything reasonable to try and type cast this as a map but I think there is something I just don't understand. FWIW I think whatever it is I'm trying to do is accessing a Future not the actual data. and I think i might be confused or unclear about async/awaits but my understanding of the code I've written is that the actions are chained one to another so I shouldn't be "waiting" for anything or getting a future, I should just be getting a string.

Otherwise, Here's my code cleaned up, any advice or suggestions on working with the data in the print would be much appreciated.

```
class ticketingsoftwareAPIProvider {
  // Object Properties
  Client _client = Client();
  final String _ApiKey = "YOUSHALLPASS!";
  final String apiRoot = "https://api.ticketingsoftware.com";
  final String agentId = '2675309';
  


    getAgentTickets() async {
        // Headers for our HTTP Request
        Map<String, String> headers = {
          'X-ticketingsoftware-Authorization': 'Bearer $_ApiKey',
          'Accept': 'application/vnd.ticketingsoftware.v2.1+json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        };
    
        await _client
            .get(Uri.parse('$apiRoot/incidents.json?assigned_to=$agentId'))
            .then((data) {
          if (data.statusCode == 200) {
            print(json.decode(data.body));
            // CANT SEEM TO MAKE THIS A INTO A MAP TO GENERATE OBJECTS WITH.
          }
        });
      }
    }
} // END CLASS
```

I apologize for any missing information, I am new to dart and REALLY programming in general and am still learning the culture. please let me know if there is any additional information that might help.

My Solution ended up being:

```
        List ticketJson = json.decode(data.body);
    for (var ticket = 0; ticket < ticketJson.length; ticket++) {
      thisAgentsTickets.add(incident.fromJson(ticketJson[ticket]));
      return thisAgentsTickets;
```

I think I've been learning from a very out of date course.

Comment: Can you show what data body is getting?

Answer (score 0):

You need `fromJson` method to convert it to an object. For example

```
 if (data.statusCode == 200) {
     return AgentTicket = AgentTicket.fromJson(data.body)
 }
```

Use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package for easy way to create the method, or you can create it manually too.